# background image to automatically Resize in table Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hello
I am Building a News letter now the letter now a requirement is to background image to some TD 
now I need to make the Image resize as their Parent TD is resized i.e if the Table width is Set to 50% or 500 or any other values I need the Background image to resize to fit the new width any Idea :)
thanks

Comment: Could you please post some of the code and use styling, its bit hard to understand what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS3 you can resize your background with the `background-size` property:

Adding this to your CSS will stretch the background to 100% width and 100% height, in the latest browsers.

```
td {background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

This may undesirably skew the image however, so you'll probably prefer to use just `background-size: 100%;` which sets the width to 100% and the height to auto.

To support slightly older browsers you'll need to use vendor prefixes, like so:

```
-moz-background-size: 100%; /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
-o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.5 */
-webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.0 */
-khtml-background-size: 100%; /* Konqueror 3.5.4 */
-moz-border-image: url(mtn.jpg) 0; /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
```

The above example [is from this site](http://ioconnor.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/automatically-resizing-background-images-with-css3/), and the full spec is here - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size